# jQuery variable within a selector

Tags: jquery, html

I need `$('.mk[value=x]')` to work, but it does Not while `$('.mk[value=1]')` does.
Please someone help

```
<body>
<span class="mk" value="1">1</span>
<span class="mk" value="1">1</span>
<span class="mk" value="3">3</span>
<input id="update" type="button" value="1" />
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#update').click(function(){
    var x = this.value //--> x =1 
       $('.mk[value=x]').each(function(key, value) { //--> NOT WORKING !
       $('.mk[value=1]').each(function(key, value) { //--> WORKING !
       $(this).replaceWith('<span class="mk" value="2">2</span>')
       });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to append the `x` variable to the string:

```
$(".mk[value='" + x + "']").each(function(key, value)
```

Also, you should note that `value` is not a valid attribute of `span`, so this code will cause validation issues.

Comment: +1 for (aside from being _right_) quoting the attribute value in the selector.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: Quotes for simple attribute values are not required.

Comment: @amnotiam they may not be required, but they are good practice IMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer !

Answer (score 1):

Try that way:

```
$('.mk[value='+x+']').each(
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either concatenate it to the string

```
$('.mk[value='+ x +']').each(function(key, value)
```

or use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

```
$('.mk').filter(function(){return this.value === x;}).each(function(key, value)
```

---

or since you already use `each` on them you can do the filtering there

```
$('.mk').each(function(key, value) {
      if (this.value === x) {
          this.replaceWith('<span class="mk" value="2">2</span>');
      }
   });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't work is that `'.mk[value=x]'` is a standard string and it doesn't get parsed.

Try changing the selector to `'.mk[value=' + x + ']'` and x will be replaced with the variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$('.mk[value=x]')
```

to

```
$('.mk[value='+x+']')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your value into the selection string like this:

```
$('#update').click(function(){
var x = this.value 
 $(".mk[value='" + x + "']").each(function(key, value) {
  this.replaceWith('<span class="mk" value="2">2</span>')
 });
})
```